# Blender Hair Dynamic not working with both force field and collision

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I am new to blender Hair Dynamic, and I am trying to create a hair that would react with the world.
I have made the sample file and it does not work.
I tried all tutorials I can find, and I don't know what I have missed.
Please help me with this and tell me what's going on.
Here is the link to my file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H7VsX17Ny1vikSTvEBbntGN6-iNDRAwS

Answer (score 0):

So, I have fiddled around with my model, and I saw one post says that before certain version the Hair won't collide with itself.
My understanding is it should be able to collide with it self now, but somehow mine didn't.
(someone save me on this part pls)
[image: Some hair is still going through, but good enough]
I made a new mesh, used collision(as in image), and I achieved some collision but some hair is still going through.
note that the thing will now have any collision if it is hided (the eye button). I hope this helped those have the same problem with me.
(And please post better solution if you have one.)